# ZeroMQ: Can we .bind() 100+ sockets to the same endpoint?

Tags: sockets, zeromq

Is it a good idea to have multiple **`PUSH`** sockets **`.bind()`** to the same endpoint?
1) If yes, how can multiple **`PULL`** sockets `.connect()` to this endpoint and start receiving messages?

Answer (score 1):

### No, the first `.bind()` typically grabs the resource ( ref. the `port` )

The next thing is, that **`PUSH`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern has a hardwired "internal behaviour" - the API table says:

> `Outgoing routing strategy     Round-robin`

so, if there were more than one active transport-class connections to the **`PUSH`**-node archetype, it will cyclically distribute the outgoing messages to the connected, active `PULL`-node peers ( in a uniform load-ballancing, literally in the "round-robin" manner ).

However, it is possible to groom the intended outgoing traffic from several **`PUSH`**-ers ( by a local mediator / job-collector ) and expose such uniformly collected flow of jobs ( messages ) under a single "public" `PUSH`-ing node to all the external `PULL`-er(s) ( all the currently active peers get served on the round-robin basis + decide on using the **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_IMMEDIATE )`** )